# mysql [Err] 1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: mysql

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `usersToChanges` AFTER INSERT ON tbl1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.id=tbl1.id;
INSERT INTO tbl3 (col1,col2,col3, col4, col5,col6) 
        VALUES (456,NOW(),'test','test',46000,123);
END
```

i want to create a trigger like above. i need to select data from tbl2 because the values to be inserted in tbl3 come from tbl2. the values shown here are just dummy values . And i am getting error [Err] 1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER `usersToChanges` AFTER INSERT ON tbl1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO tbl3 (col1,col2,col3, col4, col5,col6) 
SELECT 456,NOW(),'test','test',46000,123 
FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.id=NEW.id;
END
```

Comment: This is mostly correct since the question asker did not specify the column names of `tbl2`. They will need to be replaced in the select list. I missed that part in my original answer so I deleted it. One thing to note. The reason the original poster was getting the error is because the stand alone `SELECT` will attempt to return a record set from the procedure block it is executed in. Moving it into the `INSERT` properly associates it with that statement to control the data going into the `INSERT` instead of attempting to return it from the trigger.

Comment: No. 456,NOW(),'test','test',46000,123  these are the values that should come from tbl2. here these are just dummy values.

Comment: #wogsland I have tried like u answered i get this. 

unknown column inserted.id in where clause.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause will be something that you need to edit. You will need to use whatever primary key `tbl2` is keyed off of from `tbl1` (or `inserted`). What is the `Foreign Key` relationship between `tbl1` and tbl2`?

Comment: i have tried that as well.

like where tbl2.id=tbl1.id

Comment: Try now. I replaced `inserted` with `NEW`.